# How do I change a css property of an undeclared element?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I have some elements (in particular, a div containing an iframe) that are added to a panel in an html page using php, so are not included nor declared in the beginning.

At the same time, this two elements have some CSS properties already declared in an appropriate stylesheet; I want to change the size of these two elements dynamically, once when the page is loaded, and at every resize of the page.


I'm trying to do so in this way, in jQuery (the div has id "wrap", the iframe has id "frame"):

```
var h = $(window).height()*0.8;
var w = $(window).width()*0.3;
$("#wrap").css(height, h);
$("#wrap").css(width, w);
$("#frame").css(height, h);
$("#frame").css(width, w);

$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    var h = $(window).height()*0.8;
    var w = $(window).width()*0.3;
    $("#wrap").css(height, h);
    $("#wrap").css(width, w);
    $("#frame").css(height, h);
    $("#frame").css(width, w);
});
```

All this code is in the $(document).ready function.
For some reasons it doesn't work: I've checked many times, and it seems that jQuery is unable to change the properties of elements not already declared in the page, such as "wrap" or "frame". 
Any idea about how to solve the problem?



**EDIT:** I tried the methods suggested in the answer, but while it resolves the errors (I noted that the page rendering stopped after declaring those elements), still there are no changes in the visual effect of the div and the iframe.

The ajax call is like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'SetFrame.php',
            headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: "uri=" + uri,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) {
                loadBar();
                $("#panelP").empty();
                $("#panelP").append(result);
                scrollBar();
                refreshSize();
            },

            error: function (){
                alert("ERROR");
            }


        });
```

refreshSize() is this function, just prepared:

```
function refreshSize()
{
    var h = $(window).height()*0.8;
    var w = $(window).width()*0.3;
    $("#wrap").css(height, h);
    $("#wrap").css(width, w);
    $("#frame").css(height, h);
    $("#frame").css(width, w);
}
```

Comment: *"I have some elements (in particular, a div containing an iframe) that are added to a panel in an html page using php, so are not included nor declared in the beginning."* By the time your **client-side** JavaScript is running, your **server-side** PHP is done running. So if PHP is generating these elements, your client-side code can access them (if it's in the correct place on the page [at the bottom], or as a second-best solution if you use jQuery's `ready`). You're already using `ready`, so the problem isn't what you think it is. You'll need to look at things with the debugger.

Comment: Check the entire HTML of the page you put that javascript, for the referred elements. If you call PHP by Ajax, then only after the call and output to the page DOM is that you will be able to refer to the elements.

Comment: What they said. Show us the ajax function.

Comment: Check the edit, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to duplicate your code, you can simply trigger the `resize` as soon as you have declared the event handling code.

Wrap the code in a `ready` handler to make sure elements exist when it is first run

```
$(function(){    
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        var h = $(window).height()*0.8;
        var w = $(window).width()*0.3;
        $("#wrap").css(height, h);
        $("#wrap").css(width, w);
        $("#frame").css(height, h);
        $("#frame").css(width, w);
    // now trigger this event to set dimensions for these elements (if they exist)
    }).resize();
});
```

If the elements are loaded after initial page load you can again trigger the resize event when they exist in the DOM by calling `$(window).resize()`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, because I think it's better organized:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    refreshSize();
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    refreshSize();
});

var refreshSize = function() {
    var h = $(window).height()*0.8;
    var w = $(window).width()*0.3;
    $("#wrap").css('height', h);
    $("#wrap").css('width', w);
    $("#frame").css('height', h);
    $("#frame").css('width', w);
};
```

I think its just a preference though.

**EDIT:** 
Please note that within your `.css` function you are calling css `height` and `width` without apostrophe `''` !!